# Unable to see GUI

Tags: gui, virtualization, vmware

Hey I have Installed UBUNTU 12.04 on vmware work station on Windows 7 but when I start  it up in vmware I get a message on black screen of ubuntu i.e.

```
[ 7.3326] pixx4_smbus 0000:00:07.3: Host SMBus controller not enabled!
```

After that it asks for user id and password on black screen and after entering them I am still in a black screen, I am unable to see GUI.

Please suggest what to do. I am new to UBUNTU.

Comment: First of all, let's see if you have a desktop installed. Log in, and type: `startx`+Enter.

Answer (score 2):

The SMBus is for information such as motherboard temperature and there isn't any on a virtual machine (as far as I am aware), but Linux still starts the driver for it. I am fairly sure it isn't related to your GUI issue.

Sorry if this sounds Mickey Mouse, but did you install Ubuntu workstation or server? The server hasn't got a GUI by default. Workstations put the GUI in terminal 7. You can switch terminal screens by pressing CTRL+ALT+F7 (F1 to F7 selects the different screens). So when your VM starts, try pressing CTRL+ALT+F7 and see what's on the screen. If it's just another logon prompt, then the GUI isn't working or not installed. Log in and try typing startx to see if the GUI strats. If not, check the messages you get and let us know.

If you've installed server and want a GUI, there are quite a few to be had. Some are lightweight and some are extremely heavy. One of the lighter is xfce4.

Comment: Thanks buddy, but now its sound driver is not working. please suggest me what to do.

Comment: In your Ubuntu VM I would type lspci at the command prompt and see whether the audio device shows up in the list. If not, you maybe need to check the settings on the VMWare host to see whether the audio device is enabled etc.